# Why there is no output in DIV?

Tags: jquery, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch data from MySQL to my client page using jQuery Ajax. I wrote this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Salman Test Ajax Select Box</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
            $.post("func.php", function(data, status) {
                $("#ajax").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <select id="parent_cat" name="parent_cat">

            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a Category</option>
            <option id="opt" value="1">1</option>
            <div id="ajax"></div>
        </select>

        <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;"> <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Please Wait"> </span>
    </form>
</body>
```

But there is no output in the DIV but if I change the line `$('#ajax').html(data);` to `alert(data);` it works perfect.

Comment: You have the `div` tag inside a `select` tag.  This is likely hiding or not rendering the `div`.  Move it outside.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, your `<div>` is in the `<select>` tag, which probably disrupts the rendering. Move the div one line below, just after your select, and it should works.